# Uable to set check box to checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've grabbed some CSS to beautify my check boxes and ever since they set them selves to checked when clicked and I'm not sure where the issue is.  The CSS is:

```
.time-check-input{
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  label {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #fcfff4;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    &:after {
      content: '';
      width: 9px;
      height: 5px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 4px;
      left: 4px;
      border: 3px solid #333;
      border-top: none;
      border-right: none;
      background: transparent;
      opacity: 0;
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
    &:hover::after {
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
  }
  input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
    &:checked + label:after {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }    
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="time-check">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" class="time-check-input" id="{{level.LevelTmsCode}}-{{day.Day}}-open" name="check"/>
    <label for="{{level.LevelTmsCode}}-{{day.Day}}-open" class="time-check-input"></label> <span>Open</span>
</div>
```

I don't mind doing it with JavaScript - it doesn't have to be all with CSS but obviously I would prefer as little JS as/Jquery as possible.

Comment: Check the answer, this should be what you want

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question, why have you provided a load of CSS when your HTML doesn't even use the class the CSS is specified with?

Comment: Copy and paste error .squaredFour should be .time-check-input

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript way to set the checkbox `checked`

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('time-check-input')[0].checked = true;
```

```html
<div class="time-check">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" class="time-check-input" id="{{level.LevelTmsCode}}-{{day.Day}}-open" name="check"/>
    <label for="{{level.LevelTmsCode}}-{{day.Day}}-open" class="time-check-input"></label> <span>Open</span>
</div>
```

If you want to use JQuery then:

```js
$('.time-check-input').attr('checked',true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="time-check">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" class="time-check-input" id="{{level.LevelTmsCode}}-{{day.Day}}-open" name="check"/>
    <label for="{{level.LevelTmsCode}}-{{day.Day}}-open" class="time-check-input"></label> <span>Open</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Still doesn't check the box unfortunately

Comment: What do you get ? output?errors? or you have changed your HTML?

Comment: No errors, no output, just nothing happens - HTML is still the same

Comment: It also won't check when I strip the CSS out  and take it back down to being a vanilla check box either

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might just be in your SASS/LESS, I've vanilla'd your CSS and it all works alright to me

```css
.squaredFour {
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.squaredFour label {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #fcfff4;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.squaredFour label:after {
      content: '';
      width: 9px;
      height: 5px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 4px;
      left: 4px;
      border: 3px solid #333;
      border-top: none;
      border-right: none;
      background: transparent;
      opacity: 0;
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
.squaredFour label:hover::after {
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
.squaredFour input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.squaredFour input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after
{
      opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="squaredFour time-check">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" class="time-check-input" id="{{level.LevelTmsCode}}-{{day.Day}}-open" name="check"/>
    <label for="{{level.LevelTmsCode}}-{{day.Day}}-open" class="time-check-input"></label> <span>Open</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I've change the LESS to CSS and I still can't check the box

Comment: Have you pressed Run Code Snippet on my answer? I've changed your LESS to CSS and it works fine for me.

Comment: I have yeah - and yeah it does, but for some reason it doesn't work on my code

Comment: Can you update the CSS in your question with your vanilla CSS so I can check it? Because the problem is now in your vanilla CSS, which I can't see.